# Where does arriving remote data fit into the MVC model

Tags: ios, model-view-controller

I read this question: [Understanding MVC pattern used in iOS apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674879/understanding-mvc-pattern-used-in-ios-apps), and loaded and ran the [sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html) and found it helpful to understand how to collect external data such as images from the web. I can see how the IconDowloader works with the ViewController to collect the images and return them to the ViewController via a delegate.

I do not understand where the IconDownloader (or any 'helper' that retrieves data from an external source) fits into the MVC model. It seems to be bolted onto the side of the controller to me.

Is it part of the controller?

Comment: There are model, views, controllers, but then there are other roles as well. This one looks like a ModelUtility!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IconDownloader is part of a hierarchy of controllers which collectively form 'the controller'.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the IconDownloader is a controller object. Note that the MVC pattern speaks of controllers in general, not just of *view* controllers. Besides view controllers, there can be many more controller objects that deal with other subsystem of an application.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Ole. The missing part for me was that the controller is formed from a _hierarchy_ of controller objects and that IconDownloader fits into that tree.

Comment: Can you post a reference to this definition of MVC?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457
Container View Controllers Manage Other View Controllers

Answer (score 1):

Talking about MVC in general, it should be part of Service layer, which isn't part of theoretical MVC but in real world, there is always Service layer (or called otherwise) but delegated to handle I/O read/write etc.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I see that service layer is part of a network service provider architecture but I was specifically interested where external comms fitted into MVC. I now understand that it is part of the controller in the scope of the MVC.